# Search bar round on iPad

Tags: html, css

I have one issue with the iPad version of a website. Why does it display the search bar rounded?

**normal**: 
[image: Normal Preview of the website]

on **iPad** (wrong):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add to your search bar's CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
border-radius: 0; /* optionally, or you can specify your own value */
```

This will reset the default styles of the browser